# "mount.nfs: Connection timed out" Error while installing open edX on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, mount, nfs, openedx

I am trying to install vagrant based devstack of open edX (Ginkgo)on Ubuntu 18.04.
But when I do vagrant up, execution stucks at MOUNT. And getting below error after sometime.

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.33.1:/home/sahilpatel/ginkgo/edx-platform 
/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

My system versions are below : 
Vagrant 2.2.0
Virtualbox 5.2.22r126460

Comment: Ensure the "nfsd" client is running. and I think this version supports Ubuntu 16.

And try to use docker version. not vagrant https://github.com/edx/devstack

Comment: "nfs" services are up and running.